# Can't upgrade from 19.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I am running 19.04 desktop (64bit), when I tried to upgrade, got error:

```
# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

However, I got error when doing update

```
# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease                               
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                            
Hit:4 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                            
Ign:5 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease   
Hit:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                            
Hit:7 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Release     
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                       
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peek-developers/stable/ubuntu disco InRelease
Err:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Err:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So I am stuck.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04's intended & fully-tested *release-upgrade* path was to 19.10, which closed however when Ubuntu 19.10 reached EOL earlier this year. After a release reaches EOL, it's repositories are moved (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades or https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release  I would recommend a re-install using 20.04 media, using existing partitions but without *format* so as to not lose data.

Comment: If you don't want to *release-upgrade* every 6-9 months are required by non-LTS releases, use LTS or *long-term-support* releases.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc for the pointer, I wonder if I have CD with 20.04, can I install it on top of 19.04 without destroying my existing applications, files?

Comment: If you install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using *something-else*, select your existing partition(s) and do not have *format* checked, it'll note your packages, erase system directories, install new system, then *try and re-add back your additional packages if available on the new release*. It won't touch user files unless you used format (but backup regardless). Because system directories are erased, some server *config* files will be erased; but desktop files being in $HOME aren't touched. The re-install of additional packages has very recently been removed, but I'd expect it to still work with 20.04

Comment: (I've used it many times, re: the noting of packages & having the installer add them back post-install. Because of complaints about it not handling 3rd party & other issues, it was deemed easier to remove that functionality than deal with errors caused by the non-Ubuntu (3rd) party packages, I only became aware of this in recent days thus haven't explored what the change has impacted. I doubt it exists in 20.04.1 but I've not verified this; I suspect it's *groovy* currently only, but again I've not looked yet)

Comment: Thanks @guiverc for the assuring explanation. I now have more confidence to do so.  Your comment should be turned into an answer that I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu 19.04 and 19.10 are EOL now, you might have to do a fresh install. Make a backup of all the important files. Download a new Desktop image ISO file from the official site, make an installation media and try installing afresh.
https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks @schizoid-man for the tip.  Guiverc's explanation and personal experience assured.  I will wait for him to write it as an answer first.

Comment: @packetie I voted to close as duplicate so won't write an answer. I suspect you won't be able to accept this answer, however please feel free to upvote or accept it (if you can; users with low reps like yourselves need the rep).  To schizoid_man rathar than just a link to where you can download, personally I prefer a link to the release notes https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes which provide detail useful for installing, plus links to download ISOs (inc. other choices than just desktop for *amd64*); or both if you wish (I'd have up-voted for that).

Comment: Any issues we discover in testing, or other know issues (& their workarounds) are covered in the release notes (eg. python3 replacing python2). Whilst not all make it (eg. anything Qt4 based has been removed) it's worth it just to scan quickly & first call for issues (*in my opinion at least*).

Comment: It's OK to close it. Thanks @guiverc. I guess some other users would benefit from your comments with higher confidence in performing the (dangerous) action.